# enumerate registry for installed sound drivers vb6

Tags: vb6, audio, enumeration, device-driver

I need help for a sample code to enumerate installed sound drivers in windows xp with vb6.

Can you tell me where this is stored in the registry?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i found the solution online [**`here`**](http://directx4vb.vbgamer.com/DirectX4VB/Tutorials/DirectX8/DA_SoundFx.asp)